# Changing the hover box values in Pygal/Python

Tags: python, hover, pygal

I have created a scatterplot in Python using the Pygal library.  Now, I want to change the information inside of the boxes that show up when you hover over them (I think it's called the dynamic_print_values???). I want to be able to write an explanation in it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved this yet but try this.

```
chart = pygal.XY()
chart.add('First', [{'value': (2,0.1), 'label': 'This is the first'},
                    {'value': (2.6,0.4), 'label': 'This is the second'},
                    {'value': (3.6,0.8), 'label': 'This is the third'}])
chart.render_to_file('testpy.svg')
```

In the values/series list replace your values with a dictionary item that specifies the 'value' and 'label' as per above example.